# Questions regarding databases

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc

I have a questions regarding databases for ASP.Net 4.0 MVC3 (or 4 Beta).
I'm fairly new to the ASP.net MVC environment, and usage of databases in general.

1. It's stated that the SQL Server Compact is a local database storage. What does this exactly mean? If I were to use this for my web app, would users be able to "access" this database (e.g. register, login), or would I be the only one with access since the file (.sdf) is "local" and is only in my hard disk?
2. Let's say I'm coding a library management system which would require storage of alot of stuff in the DB. Would it be better to just use the SQL Server Compact that comes with Visual Studio or should I switch to MySQL or some other databases?

I'm asking because I wanna clear everything up before I step into the world of ASP.Net (and since I'll be dealing with DBs alot in future).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The "local" is relative to where the application code runs, not where the user is. If you're using ASP.NET MVC, the application code runs on the server, to the database has to be on the same server. All users using the web application can use it though since the access is done by the application.
2. I'd use SQL Server Express for that, version 2008 R2 does have a limit of 10GB per database (not including FILESTREAM data AFAIR) but that is already a *lot* of data. It's free but uses the same engine as the full SQL Server products, but it has some limitations on database size (as mentioned) and resource usage (parallel processing and memory), for many application it is still a perfect solution though.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, in this case "local" means that it's contained within the package of the web site itself.  You'll want to deploy the database file along with the website (but take care not to overwrite it in future subsequent deployments), of course.  But the idea is that the database is a file that you put on the server, not a service installed on the server.
2. Define "a lot of stuff."  I doubt you're going to exceed the capacity of SQL Server Compact, or absolutely require features it doesn't provide.  You'll want to compare all of the features available in the various databases.  (Size limits, native data types, ease of integration, ease of management and deployment, stored procedures, etc.)  Chances are any database will work for you, but you'll have to define your needs in more terms than just "a lot of stuff."

Answer (score 0):

**1)** 
SQL SErver Compact edition is a light weight free, embedded, database engine that enables easy database storage.  That means you dont need to install any software in a computer for this database to work. you can simply copy the dll of SQL Server compact edition and put in your bin directory and start using it. No additional setup or security permissions are required for it to run.SQL Server CE Stores database as a files on disk. The file extension will be .sdf You can store SQL CE database files within the \App_Data folder of your ASP.NET Web application
Here is how it looks like in a project.

[image]

You can do the same things you did with a standard sql server express instance with SQL CE too. So your users would be able to access the data ( thru your application).

**2)** SQL Server CE would handle this up to an extend. If you have so much data coming in, you probably want to try something bigger like SQL Server express edition etc.. But the migration is easily doable because it is a miniature version of the real SQL Server Database.

If you are in a shread hosting environment and dont have the ability to install / get access to SQL Server instance, you can go with SQL Server CE as it is file based.

This is a good reading to start with : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx